# West Australia luxury beach resort

Tags: australia, beaches, luxury, resorts, perth

I am looking for a honeymoon destination (resort or hotel). The constraints:

- beach - white sandy if possible
- Western Australia - stunning views
- optional constraint: close to Perth (we intend to fly to Perth)

Any other suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: I think it's still too broad, I expect hundreds of possibilities. No constraint on the price btw?

Comment: I don't know what to expect, as I never traveled to Australia...so this is why I leave it open ended.

Comment: Are you aware of just how big Western Australia is? And how relative "close to" can be for people from / not from there? As in you'll meet some people from out there who'll say "we're quite near Perth, it's only a 12 hour drive"...

Comment: well, now I know all the things you mentioned :).

Comment: Western Australia is big but very sparsely populated. I don't know of any such resort off the top of my head but might expect something in or around Broome. Rottnest Island maybe?? I wouldn't be surprised if there are very few contenders with places of this nature more likely in the tropical islands of North Queensland. I think it's a suitable question.

Answer (score 2):

[Cable Beach Resort](http://www.cablebeachclub.com) in Broome should tick most of your boxes.  However, being a 2.5 hour flight away from Perth, it's only "close" by WA standards.  Busselton and other places around the Margaret River south of Perth are another option, but you're looking at a 2+ hour drive to get to them.

If you're looking something under an hour from Perth, there's a [fair number of pretty decent beaches](http://www.hotelclub.com/blog/perth-beaches/) nearby as well, most famously Cottesloe.  But these are all (more or less) "city" beaches, which may or may not be what you're looking for.